# ui-tinymce inside a ng-include partial

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am adding tinymce inside a partial using ng-include. This is not working. When I move the same syntax to the view file, it is loading properly. Any suggestion, how can I add tinymce inside a partial?

```
<!-- Not working inside, a HTML partial -->
<textarea ui-tinymce ng-model="data.describe"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call an instance of tinyMCE after `ng-include` is loaded. Use `$includeContentLoaded` like:

```
$scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(event) {
    // call init function of tinyMCE
}});
```

If you use a `ui-tinymce` directive, you need to edit this.